# login page is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, frameworks

Please help me.

I'm trying to create login system using codeIgniter. but i still cannot pass the login form even the value is true such as the value in the database. please help me to fix and figure out whats wrong with this.

This is database structure. Username : jeff_way and Password : jeff_way (note : encripted using md5)

[image: Database structure]

This is the Login controller

```
<?php session_start();

class Login extends CI_Controller{

function index()
{

    /*$data['main_content']='tampilan';*/
    $this->load->view('tampilan');

}


function validate_credentials()
{
    var_dump(session_id('is_logged_in'));
    var_dump($_POST);

    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query)
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' =>true   
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('site/members_area');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }

}
```

this is the model :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Membership_model extends CI_Model{

    function validate()
    {
        $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');

        if($query->num_rows() ==1)
        {
            return true;

        }
    }
```

Here is the login form view :

```
<div class="input-group container-fluid jumbotron shadow">
    <h2>Login Fool</h2>
    <?php echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');?>
    <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'username', 'class'=>'form-control jarak','placeholder'=>'Username']);?>
    <?php echo form_password(['name'=>'password', 'class'=>'form-control jarak','placeholder'=>'Password']);?>
    <?php echo form_submit(['class'=>'btn btn-default jarak','value'=>'Login']);?>
    <?php echo anchor('login/sign_up','Create Account',array('class'=>'btn btn-info jarak'));?>

    <?php form_close();?>
```

everytime i try to login, the page always sent to controller login/validate_credentrial. here is the picture :

[image]

but when i try to use var_dump($_POST) on login, it sends value.

Please help me. thanks

Comment: Tip: In codeigniter you can use there session library https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html. That way you dont have to use session_start()

Comment: And do not use MD5 for passwords not secure. Use php http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and to verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 : where session_start() placed ?. Should i use session_start() in the beggining of page?

Comment: You need to read the session library manual I added the link

Comment: If this is it I'll post it as an answer - but according to https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-helper-methods `num_rows()` is only run on a query not a get. Try using $ct = $this->db->query($this->db->get_compiled_select()); $ct->num_rows() and see if that helps?

Comment: Have you added `session` library in `config/autoload.php` file? If not than add in autoload.

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya : yes. I have already add session in autoload library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing `/login/validate_credentials` is because you are telling it to.

If you picture this... you originally display the form via `/login`.

When you submit the form it calls (goes to) the url /login/validate_credentials as defined in your forms action.

In the case the login credentials do not match your database, i.e. fails, then this causes the validate_credentials() method to call `$this->index` which simply redisplays the form. It does not alter the url.
So the resulting url will remain `/login/validate_credentials`.

If you are expecting to see /login as the url, then you will need to perform a `redirect('login');` instead.

**A note on the validate() function**
In regards to the model method validate()...
If you are going to return a value, your function should always return a value under all conditions.

So you should have something like...

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');

    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return TRUE; 
    }

    return FALSE;  // else we need to specifically return FALSE 

}
```

**UPDATE: Debug Code Added**

```
function validate() {
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');

    echo $this->db->last_query(); // DEBUG the SQL
    echo $query->num_rows;  // DEBUG how many rows

    if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

What debug info do you get from the above?

Comment: indeed, i know that my login form always goes to `/login/validate_credentials` because my form action told it. but, the problem is, if my username and password equal with the database, why it not redirect me to members_area? i stil can't find the problem. and i try add `return FALSE;` but nothing happened

Comment: Yes I misread your question. Ok I've added some debug code to help assist you to test this.

Comment: actually, there are two button. Login button and create account button. when i try to create new account, the page can direct me to members area. then i try to login with new account i've created before and it is succeded. but when i try to login again with the same username and password, the page won't direct me to member area. why is that?

Comment: So on that basis you would think to yourself..."Hmm when I login in its checking the details in the database... so if I create a new account and then try to login in, it doesn't work... So when I create a new account, are they being saved in the database table? and on and on....

Comment: when i create new account, it saved in database table. but still can't logged in through login page.

Comment: So when you compare ( see) the values from the login, do they match what is in the database? It's playing spot the difference!